# Creating nested folder with CordovFile dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise

I have to create, nested folder on android mobile, with ionic framework.
Problem is its a asynchronous request, so before finishing first folder it goes to below code to create second folder inside the first folder, as folder is not created yet, it gives an error.

I searched that it can be worked out with angular $q service, i tried it but not working, honestly i don't know how its work, below is my code.

**Controller**

```
if( $scope.projectDetails.clientId == null && $scope.projectDetails.locationId == null ){
            // insert a row in client table
            var parameters=[$scope.projectDetails.clientName];
            NewProject.insertClient(parameters).then(function(result){
               $scope.projectDetails.clientId = result.insertId;
               // create folder with this name in Renewate folder
               ProjectCreated.createFolder("Renewate",$scope.projectDetails.clientName).then(function(resolve){
                // create new location
                var parameters=[$scope.projectDetails.clientId, $scope.projectDetails.locationName];
                NewProject.insertLocation(parameters).then(function(result){
                    $scope.projectDetails.locationId = result.insertId;
                    // create folder with this name in Renewate folder
                    var folderPath = "Renewate"+"/"+$scope.projectDetails.clientName;
                    ProjectCreated.createFolder(folderPath, $scope.projectDetails.locationName).then(function(resolve){
                          var parameters=[$scope.projectDetails.projectName, $scope.projectDetails.locationId];
                          NewProject.insertProject(parameters).then(function(result){
                              $scope.projectDetails.projectId = result.insertId;
                              var folderPath = "Renewate"+"/"+$scope.projectDetails.clientName+"/"+$scope.projectDetails.locationName;
                              ProjectCreated.createFolder(folderPath, $scope.projectDetails.projectName).then(function(resolve){ 
                                  //$state.go('renewate3');
                              });
                          });
                    });

                });
            });
          });
        }
```

**Service**

```
createFolder: function(folderPath, folderName){
          var q = $q.defer();
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
              $cordovaFile.createDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+folderPath, folderName, true)
              .then(function (success) {
                q.resolve(result);
              },
              function (error) {
                  q.reject(error);
                  alert("error");
              });
          });
          return q.promise;
        },
```

Please let me know where i am mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but I'm not sure you if you actually stated that there is an error happening in *this actual* version of the code. If an error happens, it's hard to spot exactly where since it's very messy.

**Rewriting the service**

Looking at the `createFolder` function in your service, you've implemented the so called [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

The `$ionicPlatform.ready` already returns a promise (see the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)) so there is no need to create a new promise as you're doing right now. You should instead return the already existing promise like

```
return $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    return $cordovaFile.createDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+folderPath, folderName, true);
});
```

Note that the `$cordovaFile.createDir` [will throw an error](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) if it fails, and since you're not using the result/returned value, you can simply return without a then and handle the error in a higher level `.catch()`.

I'm not familiar enough with Ionic to say what is best practice and what's not, but I would look into if it's really necessary to wrap the `createFolder()` function inside the `$ionicPlatform.ready`, since it will resolve directly if called and it's already ready.

**Rewriting your promise chain**
A nice thing with promises is that we can get rid of the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)/pyramid of doom that happens when you have alot of asynchronous functions that takes callbacks. What you've done is to use promises in a nested way that doesn't really make it neither easier nor more readable for the human eye. You might want to consider refactoring your functions into something more readable.

When you return a promise from a `.then()` it will wait until that promise is resolved before continuing to the next one. When you return a value from a `.then()` handler, it will be wrapped and resolved to the next function in the promise chain. Thus, you could rewrite your code to something like below.

Define the functions

```
function createFirstFolder(result){
     $scope.projectDetails.clientId = result.insertId;
     // create folder with this name in Renewate folder
     return ProjectCreated.createFolder("Renewate", $scope.projectDetails.clientName);
}

function createNewLocation(){
    // create new location
    var parameters= [$scope.projectDetails.clientId, $scope.projectDetails.locationName];
    return NewProject.insertLocation(parameters);
}


function createSecondLevelFolder(result){
    $scope.projectDetails.locationId = result.insertId;
    // create folder with this name in Renewate folder
    var folderPath = "Renewate"+"/"+$scope.projectDetails.clientName;
    return ProjectCreated.createFolder(folderPath, $scope.projectDetails.locationName);
}

function insertNewProject(){
      var parameters = [$scope.projectDetails.projectName, $scope.projectDetails.locationId];
      return NewProject.insertProject(parameters);
}

function createNewProjectFolder(result){
    $scope.projectDetails.projectId = result.insertId;
    var folderPath = "Renewate"+"/"+$scope.projectDetails.clientName + "/" + $scope.projectDetails.locationName;
    return ProjectCreated.createFolder(folderPath, $scope.projectDetails.projectName);
}
```

And then call them like this

```
if( $scope.projectDetails.clientId == null && $scope.projectDetails.locationId == null ){
    // insert a row in client table
    var parameters=[$scope.projectDetails.clientName];

    NewProject.insertClient(parameters)
      .then(createFirstFolder)
      .then(createNewLocation)
      .then(createSecondLevelFolder)
      .then(insertNewProject)
      .then(createNewProjectFolder)
      .then(function(){
        //$state.go('renewate3'); ?
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        //Handle error
      });
}
```

which should be alot more easier on the eye as well as easier to debug!

Comment: i understand what you said regarding code read-ably, i will correct it, but when a request is send for folder creation, it starts executing the below code and exits the function, how do i stop it, to execute all request then exit function

Comment: The code will only continue to execute if the previous promise is resolved, so unless the `$cordovaFile.createDir` is resolved before the folder is actually created, it shouldn't be possible for it to continue as you said. Have you tried what I suggested? Look at how the `createFolder` function can be changed.